# Column Header Should be True

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to set column header equal to true while running through the for loop for previewing the data in Qtablewiget

```
    self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(self.df.columns))
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.df.index))
    df_array = self.df.values
    for i in range(len(self.df.index)):
        for j in range(len(self.df.columns)):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i,j,QTableWidgetItem(str(df_array[i, j])))
    self.okButton = QPushButton("OK")
    self.cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")
    self.vBoxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.vBoxLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
    self.vBoxLayout.addWidget(self.okButton)
    self.vBoxLayout.addWidget(self.cancelButton)
    self.setLayout(self.vBoxLayout)
```

I get the dataframe as output but without column headers

Comment: Tho show the headers for the columns you can try `self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().show()`.

Comment: I tried self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().show() and  self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True) but no output as such

Comment: In that case you need to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry Actually i didnt know that,but i found a way by defining then columns in a list and then calling that variable in QtableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels,thanks